# Android upgrading app without losing data

Tags: android

I have a problem, I want to upgrade my app, but I don't want to lose the data stored.

The problem is that in my database code I have this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + POINTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NETWORKS_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I also thought of all sort of data backup, so I could at least save the data, and then to the upgrade. The problem is I think I just have two options:

a) root the device
b) connect via usb

The problem is the device usb does not work. My computers does not seem to recognize it.

Is there anyway to save my data? I already tried applications Astro, Super Backup, Titanium Backup, but all of them requires root. Problem is, I can't root without an usb cable.

My tablet is an Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

In `onCreate` you can do `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"`

In `onUpdate` you can do `"ALTER TABLE"` when needed

Comment: I know I can do it, the problem is, I will still lose my current data, am I not?

Comment: No, this way you won't lose your db data, because any existing tables won't be modified in onCreate.

Comment: the thing is, when I try to update my app, it says: same package but a different signature

Comment: It can happen if  the previous package was developed on a different machine or if the previous package was built as release while you are building a debug version. Anyway, has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: but if I proceed, I lose all data. Anyway to keep it safe?

Answer (score 0):

That's the database version, not the app version.  If your DB structure is changing, you can make a smarter upgrade path.  An example from http://blog.adamsbros.org/2012/02/28/upgrade-android-sqlite-database/ would be:

```
public void onUpgrade(
        final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion,
        final int newVersion)
    {
        int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
        while (upgradeTo <= newVersion)
        {
            switch (upgradeTo)
            {
                case 5:
                    db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V5_ADD_LAST_CARD);
                    db.execSQL(SQLiteCard.V5_ADD_FAILED);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V6_ADD_IMPORT_TYPE);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    db.execSQL(SQLiteSet.V7_ADD_SHORT_FNAME);
                    break;
            }
            upgradeTo++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but when I change my my app version, wouldn't it also change my db version?

Comment: the thing is, when I try to update my app, it says: same package but a different signature

Comment: That's the signing key. Either you're using the debug key from two different systems, or you're trying to install the debug version over the production version.